# Maven Non resolvable import pom

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to add spring configuragtion client dependency to my porject. But when I try to clan/build I am getting following error:

```
Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:{spring-cloud-version} @ line 57, column 16 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar is missing. @ line 48, column 15
```

I checked the pom structure, it is absolutely correct, I also tried to delete .m2 and re run but that also didnt worked.

My Pom:

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.5
 

com.prerak
Books
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Books
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>17</java.version>

```
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>{spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have shared, you haven't specified a version for your jar. You've used a wildcard wildcard:

`<version>{spring-cloud-version}</version>`

This would normally require something like:

`<spring-cloud-version>Greenwich.RELEASE<spring-cloud-version>`

in your pom file (or a parent pom) properties to actually pull through a value.

However, your code uses a full stop:

`<spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>`

Update your property to match your wildcard and you should be good

Comment: changed, still getting same error

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:{spring-cloud.version} @ line 57, column 16
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar is missing. @ line 48, column 15
 @
```

Comment: If you're actually wanting to import spring-cloud-dependencies, it needs to be in the dependencies section (outside of dependencyManagement)

Comment: I generated it from the spring initializer, its correct.